# Select such data and parameters of the "COPY" command that the created copy of the table could not be loaded

Tags: postgresql, copy, backup

I need to make a backup using the "COPY" command that could not be restored using the "COPY" command as well.

I tried a lot of options, messed with encodings (used Cyrillic in unsupported encodings), file extensions (binary to csv, csv to txt, txt to binary), delimiters (but postgres does not accept characters larger than a byte), also used null values and rare data types.
What else can be done to ensure that the created backup cannot be restored?
The data is restored to the same table from where it was taken, so it will not be possible to change the data type in the table. The file can't be modified manually either.

Comment: 1) Well the purpose of `COPY ... TO ...` is to create a file that `COPY ... FROM ...` can use, so unless you do something to the file after it was created I don't see this working. 2) What is the point of this exercise?

Comment: The meaning of this exercise is unknown to me, but most likely, it should convince me that PostgreSQL provides all the nuances and details when creating a backup, which will help you feel confident when backing up the database. The file can't be changed manually, all changes must be made with the COPY command

Comment: If you have any hope of inducing an error it would be with `Binary Format`: *The binary format option causes all data to be stored/read as binary format rather than as text. It is somewhat faster than the text and CSV formats, but a binary-format file is less portable across machine architectures and PostgreSQL versions. Also, the binary format is very data type specific; for example it will not work to output binary data from a smallint column and read it into an integer column, even though that would work fine in text format.*

Comment: Though the fact that the `COPY` mechanism has been in use for decades and is currently used across untold numbers of instances should be sufficient reassurance.

Comment: I understood it completely. The task should confirm this fact. And I like the idea of a binary file, but it goes to a table with the same data for recovery. The task is present in the textbook of 2018, at that time the latest version was 11, but I do not know about the nuances that could be used there

Comment: I have no idea what *'...but it goes to a table with the same data for recovery.'* means? You will need to update your question with a more detailed description of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Ok, I will edit the  question. Thank you for helping to detail the problem

Comment: My original point still stands, a file you create with `COPY ... TO ...` will be readable by `COPY ... FROM ...`.